# How to connect keyboard to label and have it always show?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uikeyboard

Is it possible to just have a label as an responder to textinput from a keyboard? And furthermore I would like to leave it there.

I have tried with label.becomeFirstResponder() in viewDidAppear(), but it doesn't really seem to do anything.

Comment: why are you use `UILabel` instead of `UITextField`?

Comment: Fair question. I wanted to test a new idea for a calculator, which would look better with a label being edited rather than a textfield.

Comment: One thing is possible. Use gesture on label and if gesture detect you can become first responder to the hidden text field and in value change text field delegate method you can set label text. But it is long way.

Comment: How about using a UITextView?